# Does `git add -p` check one-to-one correspondence only MetaHead but not sentences after HunkHeader?

Tags: git, diff

I'm digging into Git code, however, there is mystery.

When I look into https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/add-patch.c#L440-L455, I thought `git add -p` compares below input and output.

```sh
# input
git diff-files -p --no-color

# output
git diff-files -p --color | {something you defined in interactive.diffFilter}
```

However, it seems they compare only MetaHead(before @@), and doesn't compare after HunkHeaders(@@ and after @@).

```sh
# input
❯ git diff-files --no-color -p
diff --git a/src/options/set.rs b/src/options/set.rs
index a9ca6be..1a32706 100644
--- a/src/options/set.rs
+++ b/src/options/set.rs
@@ -196,7 +196,7 @@ pub fn set_options(
         opt.commit_style = "raw".to_string();
         opt.hunk_header_style = "raw".to_string();
         opt.hunk_header_decoration_style = "none".to_string();
-    }
+    } //aa
 }


# output
❯ git diff-files --color -p | delta --color-only
diff --git a/src/options/set.rs b/src/options/set.rs
index a9ca6be..1a32706 100644
--- a/src/options/set.rs
+++ b/src/options/set.rs
@@ -196,7 +196,7 @@ pub fn set_options( hogehogetest
196 ⋮196 │         opt.commit_style = "raw".to_string();
197 ⋮197 │         opt.hunk_header_style = "raw".to_string();
198 ⋮198 │         opt.hunk_header_decoration_style = "none".to_string();
199 ⋮    │-    }
    ⋮199 │+    } //aa
200 ⋮200 │ }
```

As you see, it's completely different, however, `git -c 'interactive.diffFilter=delta --color-only' add -p` works.

If I edit output like,

```sh
diff --git a/src/options/set.rs b/src/options/set.rs
index a9ca6be..1a32706 100644
--- a/src/options/set.rs
+++ b/src/options/set.rs
   ### <- insert break line
@@ -196,7 +196,7 @@ pub fn set_options(
         opt.commit_style = "raw".to_string();
         opt.hunk_header_style = "raw".to_string();
         opt.hunk_header_decoration_style = "none".to_string();
-    }
+    } //aa
 }
```

`git add -p` now errors like below as expected.

```
fatal: mismatched output from interactive.diffFilter
hint: Your filter must maintain a one-to-one correspondence
hint: between its input and output lines.
```

I am really curious, why? The Git code I looked for is wrong...?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, no.

color_p and color_pend was just a line-count-number.
They don't look inside, they just compare line-count-number.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the code changed again for "[`git add -p`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ec4f70e64711cbf550b2cfc1f78ccd9325d697b7/Documentation/git-add.txt#L96)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--p))</sup> (rewritten in C): it had regressed hunk splitting in some cases, which has been corrected with Git 2.36 (Q2 2022).

See [commit 7008ddc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7008ddc645cf8a6783d23b4ccdae0b74b096bd9e), [commit d16632f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d16632f6942568019dec21447da1ecc58dba98e0) (11 Jan 2022) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ec4f70e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ec4f70e64711cbf550b2cfc1f78ccd9325d697b7), 09 Feb 2022)</sup>

> ### [`builtin add -p`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7008ddc645cf8a6783d23b4ccdae0b74b096bd9e): fix hunk splitting
>
> <sup>Reproted-by: SZEDER Gábor</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Phillip Wood</sup>

> The C reimplementation of "`add -p`" fails to split the last hunk in a file if hunk ends with an addition or deletion without any post context line unless it is the last file to be processed.
>
> To determine whether a hunk can be split a counter is incremented each time a context line follows an insertion or deletion.
> If at the end of the hunk the value of this counter is greater than one then the hunk can be split into that number of smaller hunks.
>
> If the last hunk in a file ends with an insertion or deletion then there is no following context line and the counter will not be incremented.
> This case is already handled at the end of the loop where counter is incremented if the last hunk ended with an insertion or deletion.
>
> Unfortunately there is no similar check between files (likely because the perl version only ever parses one diff at a time).
> Fix this by checking if the last hunk ended with an insertion or deletion when we see the diff header of a new file and extend the existing regression test.